# Hack: Disable click click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm hacking a gallery plugin where I want to disable the click event for the thumbnail and  replace it with a hover event.

This is what I did: http://jsbin.com/enezol/3

```
$(function() {

  var galleries = $('.ad-gallery').adGallery();


  $('.ad-thumb-list a').hover(function() {
    $(this).click();
  });

   $('.ad-thumb-list a').click(function() {
    return false;
  });


});
```

The plugin doesn't allow me to set event to use. So Instead of changing it from their code, I'll just add a little tweak on top of it.

So I want to disable the click event for the 'thumbnail' and just use 'hover' event instead.

Any got and ideas? I'm also open to other approach as long as it meets my requirement.

Thank You!

---

Trying to implement Steph Skardal and Nicosunshine suggestion:

```
var thumbs = $('.ad-thumb-list a'),
    oldfunction = thumbs.data("events").click["function () {  context.showImage(i); context.slideshow.stop(); return false; }"];

thumbs.unbind("click").hover(oldFunction);
```

---

edit: My Solution:

I use return false to restrict it from going to the url but it does not restrict in calling the function. Any alternative ideas?

```
 var galleries = $('.ad-gallery').adGallery();

    var thumbs = $('.ad-thumb-list a');

    thumbs .hover(
        function () {
            $(this).click();
        },
        function () {

        }
    );

    thumbs.click( function () { return false; });
```

Comment: try `$('this').trigger('click');`

Comment: Are you saying you want the hover to cause an automatic click of the `<a>` element but at the same time the user should not be able to click it manually? Note that if you pass only one function to `.hover()` your function will be called both on mouseenter and mouseleave. @mgraph - `.click()` with no params is a shortcut to `.trigger('click')`, and `$('this')` should not have quotes around `this`.

Comment: yes that's what exactly i'm trying to do. thanks for pointing the quotes and the hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to unbind the `click` method and then bind the original function to the `hover`.

If you can't get the original function you can get it by seeing what the console returns if you throw:

```
$('.ad-thumb-list a').data("events").click; //name of the property that has the function
```

then you grab that function and do:

```
var thumbs = $('.ad-thumb-list a'),
    oldfunction = thumbs.data("events").click["theValueYouGotInTheConsole"];

thumbs.unbind("click")
      .hover(oldFunction);
```

Edit:

[Here](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg33/scaled.php?server=33&filename=examplerq.jpg&res=medium) is an example of what I ment with `"theValueYouGotInTheConsole"`, in the image I'm accessing the click property, and then the "4" is where the function is stored.

If you don't want to hardcode the value you can do:

```
var dataEvents = thumbs.data("events").click,
    oldFunction;

for(var functionEvent in dataEvents) {
     oldFunction = dataEvents[functionEvent];
     break; //I'm assuming there's only one event
}
```

Comment: I think the method doesn't have a name. coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery

Comment: @Pennf0lio check if you're getting the elements you want logging `$('.ad-thumb-list a')`, if that returns `[]` the selector is wrong.

Comment: yes it's returning the elements properly. I'm trying to do your suggestion. Is my code above right? I can't seem to call the function.

Thanks!

Comment: there's an error in the `"theValueYouGotInTheConsole"` part. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It seem that it's just pulling one image or just store a single data.

http://jsbin.com/enezol/8

Below of that (commented version) is what i'm playing..

Comment: @Pennf0lio ok, this was far more complicated than I tought, look at this http://jsbin.com/enezol/11/edit I think it solves your problem

Comment: @Nicoshine Yes this is what i'm looking for... Thanks so much Nico! really for taking time to look at it...

Comment: @Pennf0lio you're welcome, sorry for not commenting what I did.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. This might be irrelevant, But do you do freelance? I was wondering how can I get in touch with you.
Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [jQuery's unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method, to unbind the click event. It will have to be called after the plugin is called. E.g.:

```
$('.ad-thumb-list a').unbind('click');
```

Comment: wouldn't this disable my function to my hover too? because I'm calling an click event with my hover event...

Comment: Yes. Instead of adding $(this).click(); inside of the hover method, can you add the actual code called by the plugin by the original click method?

Comment: Not sure which method is being called. I tried this out           link.click(
            function() {
              context.showImage(i);
              context.slideshow.stop();
              return false;
            }
          ) 


but didn't work for me